# how to split a dictionary with ndarray as value for keys

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary with 10 values with keys 1-10 and  value for each key is ndarray  of dimension(126,1024). I want to split this dictionary into chunks of size 5 so result will be two dictionaries of size 5 each. My code is below:

```
pp=0
def chunks(data, SIZE=2):
    it = iter(data)
    for i in range(0, len(data), SIZE):
        yield {(i,k) for (i,k) in islice(it, SIZE)}

for item in chunks({(i,np.array(k)) for (i,k) in data_dic.items()}, 5):
    pp=pp+1
    dump_dic(item,pp)
    #print(item)
```

This code gives me an error of **unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'** in line:
  `for item in chunks({(i,np.array(k)) for (i,k) in data_dic.items()}, 5):`

could anyone suggest me how to split this dictionary with ndarray data?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
dic = {1:np.zeros((20,20)), 2:np.zeros((20,20)), 3:np.zeros((20,20)), 4:np.zeros((20,20)), 5:np.zeros((20,20)), 6:np.zeros((20,20)), 7:np.zeros((20,20)), 8:np.zeros((20,20)), 9:np.zeros((20,20)), 10:np.zeros((20,20))}    
import math
num = 3 #number of dictionaries, in your question you said 2(5, 5),i added 3 dic (3, 3, 4) 
arr = []
for i in range(num):
    if i == num -1:
       arr.append(math.ceil(len(dic) / 3))
    else:        
       arr.append(math.floor(len(dic) / 3))


dic_list = []
m = 0
for i in arr:
   k = 1
   temp = {}
   for j in list(dic.values())[m:m+i]:
      temp[k] = j
      k += 1    
   dic_list.append(temp)    
   m = i  

# So you end up with array  of dictionaries. with 3, 3, 4 data
```

example:
Input

```
{1:np.array(), 2:np.array(), 3:np.array(), 4:np.array(), 5:np.array(), 6:np.array(), 7:np.array(), 8:np.array(), 9:np.array(), 10:np.array()}
```

output

```
  [{1:np.array(), 2:np.array(), 3:np.array()}, {4:np.array(), 5:np.array(), 6:np.array()}, {7:np.array(), 8:np.array(), 9:np.array(), 10:np.array()}]
```

Comment: i did't completely understand your question.But hope this helps you :)

Comment: In actual the dictionary size is larger than 10,000, I just posted question with 10 key values.

Comment: my question is actually how I can split this ndarray data of dictionary values to put in several dictionaries of smaller size.